# If a cell in column A in sheet 2 equal to a value from sheet 1 then return the values from sheet 2 to column B and c in sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to do a kind of automatic cell updates on excel, which is a status update for a product we got and the location of the product in the warehouse.

I have basic knowledge of VBA and I didn't manage to code anything to help me with that. I tried to use If function, but didn't make sense because I can't find a way to achieve what I need.

Here is sheet 1

[image: Sheet one]

and sheet 2

[image]

examples.

This is what I am trying to achieve: 
if a cell within Sheet2 column A range = Cell A2 in sheet 1, then fill Sheet1, B2 cell and Sheet1, C2 cell with the information from sheet2 on the condition that it is the most recent entry (in the example images it is the entry with the dispatched status)

Would you recommend VBA or using formulas, and if so what should I do?

Comment: How many possible `Status` value do you have? 3?

Comment: I have 5 status values in total

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with formulas, however getting the latest value isn't as easy as it seems. This can be achieved however by following [this tutorial](https://exceljet.net/how-to-lookup-first-and-last-match) for reference. I especially refer to the part using `LOOKUP(`.

Other than that, all you need to do is set your ranges to refer to the correct sheet.

```
=IFNA(LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet2!A:A=Sheet1!A2),Sheet2!B:B),"")
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try that out

Answer (score 0):

[image]

My formula in B2 is:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B;MAX(SI(Sheet2!$A:$A=Sheet1!A2;ROW(Sheet2!$A:$A)-MIN(ROW(Sheet2!$A:$A))+1)))
```

My formula in C2 IS:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$C:$C;MAX(SI(Sheet2!$A:$A=Sheet1!A2;ROW(Sheet2!$A:$A)-MIN(ROW(Sheet2!$A:$A))+1)))
```

> **Both formulas are array formulas** so instead of entering them with <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, they must be entered pressing
>   <kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> at same time

Anyways, these formulas will probably make your file heavy and slower. Think about redesigning the way you save data, and consider adding a date field, and resuming data with Pivot Tables.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out